# Empty default custom spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner

I added all the necessary items in my spinner but I want to make the first one as a empty default like "Choose Category" at the first place of the item. How can I make first one as a empty default?

Here is my code

```
private Spinner customSpinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
    //CUSTOM SPINNER----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    customSpinner=findViewById(R.id.customSpinner);

    // create spinneritemlist for spinner
    ArrayList<CustomItems> customList = new ArrayList<>();
    customList.add(new CustomItems("Cat",R.drawable.ic_)); //30dp vector asset
    customList.add(new CustomItems("Dog",R.drawable.ic_));
    customList.add(new CustomItems("Elephant",R.drawable.ic_));
    customList.add(new CustomItems("item 2",R.drawable.ic_));
    customList.add(new CustomItems("item 3",R.drawable.ic_));
    customList.add(new CustomItems("4",R.drawable.ic_));
    customList.add(new CustomItems("5",R.drawable.ic_));
    customList.add(new CustomItems("c",R.drawable.ic_));
    customList.add(new CustomItems("shark",R.drawable.ic_));
    customList.add(new CustomItems("Pet",R.drawable.ic_));
    customList.add(new CustomItems("Toys",R.drawable.ic_));
    customList.add(new CustomItems("Others",R.drawable.ic_));

    // create Adapter for spinner
    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, customList);

    if (customSpinner != null) {
        customSpinner.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        customSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
    //CUSTOM SPINNER----------------------------------------------------------------------------


}
//CUSTOM SPINNER--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    CustomItems items = (CustomItems) adapterView.getSelectedItem();
    Toast.makeText(this, items.getSpinnerText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
//CUSTOM SPINNER--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: customList.add(new CustomItems("Choose Category",R.drawable.ic_));

Comment: customSpinner.setSelection(0); //set default selection to 0

Answer (score 1):

You can try this method to achieve a placeholder for your spinner

```
ArrayList<CustomItems> customList = new ArrayList<>();
customList.add(new CustomItems("Cat",R.drawable.ic_)); //30dp vector asset
customList.add(new CustomItems("Dog",R.drawable.ic_));
customList.add(new CustomItems("Elephant",R.drawable.ic_));
customList.add(new CustomItems("Select Animal",R.drawable.ic_)); <- This
```

In your CustomAdapter override `getCount` method

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return customList.length - 1;
}
```

And in your onCreate function after setting up the adapter

```
customSpinner.setSelection(customList.length - 1);
```